# Circle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I am given a lot of points and the points are suppose to be from a rectangle. I'm required to calculate the boundary of the rectangle.(which is relatively easy) But I also have to figure out radius of a candle(cylinder) that could be anywhere in the rectangle. All of this from just the given points. I would appreciate if someone could suggest ways to achieve this.

The points in my case are measurements of a robot wandering through this rectangle, and the empty circle is a pole of a certain unknown radius inside the rectangle that the robot can hit. So I need to figure out the radius of the pole in order to avoid that. I need to estimate the pole. It doesn't have to be exact. I'm expecting robot measurements to be enough that they'd give me pretty good idea where pole is.

Comment: Find the four edges. Calculate the distances to the center. Take the minimum.

Comment: Finding the edges is relatively easy. One can find [min x, miny, max x, max y] by just looping through all the given points and can be pretty sure of the boundary, as I'm assuming the given points are enough. I'm thinking about an efficient way to find the empty circle inside the rectangle. Empty circle doesn't necessarily have to be at the center of the rectangle.

Comment: There are an infinite number of empty circles of maximum size for any rectangle that isn't also a square.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't given the full picture. The points in my case are measurements of a robot wandering through this rectangle, and the empty circle is a pole  of a certain unknown radius inside the rectangle that the robot can hit. So I need to figure out the radius of the pole in order to avoid that. I need to **estimate** the pole. It doesn't have to be exact. I'm expecting robot measurements to be enough that they'd give me pretty good idea where pole is.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, just rasterize the area, mark the affected pixels, then start "growing" areas around them until they meet (this will give you raster versions of their Voronoi regions). The pixel (inside the rectangle) with the largest distance to any point will likely be the empty circle's center.

Alternatively, you can do a Delauney triangulation, find the largest triangle inside the rectangle, and add its neighbours while they form a convex shape. That shape will be an approximation of the circle.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? I have been trying to figure out both of these methods but haven't been able to reach anywhere. I have never worked in either of them. Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: "Rasterization" just means that you project your points on a regular 2d grid/array (like rendering on s screen). "Growing" Voronoi regions means that you mark the cells ('pixels') occupied by some points, then iteratively mark their neighbours that are not yet marked (works best with a queue that holds the 'last marked' front). To make sure your Voronoi regions grow as circles instead of squares, at a given step you can only check neighbours within a certain Euclidean distance to their "seed" point.

As for Delauney triangulation, there should be enough samples on the net.